# How to solve the problem of dry lips

Tags: oral-health, environmental-climate, dry-lips, weather, air-temperature

I speak quite a lot in my job, get my mouth dry, so I drink some water. But my lips get extremely dry. 
Are there some ways to prevent it?

I live in a subtropical weather, temperatures range from 0 to 30 Celsius. I drive to work, no motorcycle.

Comment: Dry mouth could be a symptom of different things, consider seeing a medical provider about that if you are concerned.  But regarding just SYMPTOM RELIEF for your lips - consider emollients that help prevent moisture from escaping.  Lip balms or petroleum jelly are commonly used for this.